# Google Play: How to change com.comp_name for published applications

Tags: android, google-play, application-name

Due to some initial wrong settings, the code developed for the application is in the form com.comp_name.app_name.
We have noticed after the application was published this discrepancy.
We would like to know and to understand if:

1. We can change this to com.correct_comp_name.app_name. As you can see only comp_name should be changed to correct_comp_name
2. If the change can be executed, when it would appropriate to change it? In the next release?
3. How would this change affect the application? In other words, the new release which will have the com.correct_comp_name.app_name in the top level code will still be linked to the previous app release and seen as a continuation of the initial release?

The application name, described above as app_name is the correct one and doesn't require any change.

Thank you for your support,
VN

Comment: If you are talking about package name then you can't change it once you publish it. You have to  push a new application for that.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't change the package name after publishing to play store.

but you can do the following :

1. prepare update for the current app which will check some flag from your API to detect is new app published or not to the store.  (will be explained below)

- if it's published and there is application with new package name then you open intent to this app
- if it's published and there is no application with new package name then open intent to google play to your app to inform user to download the new app.

2. submit the updates to user when it's ready.
3. change package name of your app and create new application on google play and submit the new app with new package name.
4. when your app gets approved un publish your old app and put a link in description to the new app

now if app is not published yet to store users will be still able to use current app.
when app gets published the user has to install new app to continue using.

this is the best way to do it as I did it to my app when gets same problem.